# Is $G=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb{R}): A^2=I_2\}$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am investigating whether $G=\{A\in M_2(\mathbb{R}): A^2=I_2\}$ is a group. It is clear that associativity and existence of identity and inverse are satisfied. So it only remains to determine wether $G$ is closed under matrix multiplication. Then, we consider $A,B\in G$ so that $$(AB)^2=ABAB.$$ After this point I couldn't think of a way to prove (or disprove) that $ABAB$ is $I_2$, even though I tried to use to the facts that $A=A^{-1}$, $B=B^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}A^{-1}=(AB)^{-1}.$

I am mostly looking for hints.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is NOT a group. In fact we have
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right), \quad B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right) \in G
$$
since
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)=I_2,\\
B&=&\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)=I_2.
\end{eqnarray}
But
$$
P:=AB=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right) \notin G,
$$
because we have
$$
P^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&-1\end{array}\right)=-I_2.
$$

Comment: So, is the only way to do this finding a relevant counterexample?

Comment: Not necessarily. Using @Ted Shifrin's idea, take two reflections $S, S' \in G$, say about the lines $\mathbb{R}(1,0)$ and $\mathbb{R}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, respectively, with $\theta\ne \pi/2 \mod \pi$. Then $R=SS'$ and $R^2$ are the (linear) rotations with angles $2\theta$ and $4\theta$, respectively. Since $4\theta \ne 0 \mod 2\pi$, it follows that $R^2\ne I_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Among the solutions of $A^2=I$ are the reflections about any line through the origin. What is the product of two reflections?